# get the top counts from tuple combinations

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples. Each tuple is a key value pair, in which the key is a number and the value is a string of characters. For each key I need to return the top two characters and their counts in list form.

For example, given the list

```
[(1, "aabbc"), (1, "babdea"), (2, "aabacc"), (2, "acdad")]
```

the keys are 1 and 2 and the values are

```
"aabbc", "babdea", ..., "acdaad"
```

the tuples can be  transformed into tuples of the form

```
(1, {"a":2, "b":2, "c":1}),(1,{"a":2, "b":2, "d":1,"e":1})...(2,{"a":2, "c":1, "d":2})
```

for key 1, the combined tuple would be

```
(1,{"a":4, "b":4, "c":1, "d":1,"e":1})
```

so the top two characters with their counts would be

```
[("a",4),("b",4)]
```

the process would be repeated for each key

I was able to get my desired output, but I am looking for a better solution

```
from collections import Counter
l=[(x[0],list(x[1])) for x in [(1, "aabbc"), (1, "babdea"), (2, "aabacc"), (2, "acdad")]]
l2=[(y[0],Counter(y[1])) for y in l]

l3=[(x[0][1],x[1][1]) for x in it.combinations(l2,2) if x[0][0]==x[1][0]  ]

l4=[]
for t,y in l3:
    d={}
    l5=list(set(t.keys()).union(y.keys()))
    for i in l5:
        d[i]=t[i]+y[i]
    d_sort=sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:2]

    l4.append(d_sort)


print l4
[[('a', 4), ('b', 4)], [('a', 5), ('c', 3)]]
```

Comment: Is your list sorted by keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also concatenate de strings with same key, then count the characters and extract the two most common characters:

```
import collections

data = [(1, "aabbc"), (1, "babdea"), (2, "aabacc"), (2, "acdad")]

groups = collections.defaultdict(str)
for i, s in data: 
   groups[i] += s 

print([collections.Counter(string).most_common(2)
       for string in groups.values()])
```

You'll get:

```
[[('a', 4), ('b', 4)], [('a', 5), ('c', 3)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `defaultdict` that holds `Counter`s which are updated while iterating through your list of tuples:

```
>>> from collections import Counter, defaultdict
>>> data = [(1, "aabbc"), (1, "babdea"), (2, "aabacc"), (2, "acdad")]
>>> 
>>> result = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> for num, letters in data:
...     result[num].update(letters)
... 
>>> result
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {1: Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'c': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1}), 2: Counter({'a': 5, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'b': 1})})
```

In order to get the two most common letters, the `Counter` objects have a helpful `most_common` method.

```
>>> {k:v.most_common(2) for k,v in result.items()}
{1: [('a', 4), ('b', 4)], 2: [('a', 5), ('c', 3)]}
```

Comment: and then, you can use `Counter.most_common(2)` to get the most common letter for each counter.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I overlooked that, yes. It's a little more complicated because OP wants ALL the most common elements from each Coutner. Working on that...

Comment: He wants the two most commons: `[c.most_common(2) for c in result.values()]`

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE ah, that makes it easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Not considerably better, but much shorter:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter


lst = [(1, "aabbc"), (1, "babdea"), (2, "aabacc"), (2, "acdad")]

[Counter(''.join(list(zip(*y[1]))[1])).most_common(2) for y in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])]

# [[('a', 4), ('b', 4)], [('a', 5), ('c', 3)]]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is not sorted, I would do:

```
from collections import Counter 
di={}
for i, s in data:
    di.setdefault(i, Counter())
    di[i]+=Counter(s)

print [c.most_common(2) for _,c in sorted(di.items())]
```

If it is already sorted, you can use `groupby` and `reduce`:

```
from itertools import groupby 
li=[]
for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda t: t[0]):
    li.append(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, (Counter(t[1]) for t in g)).most_common(2))

print li
```

Either case, prints:

```
[[('a', 4), ('b', 4)], [('a', 5), ('c', 3)]]
```